# I need a workaround for Excel Guessing Data Types issue using ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc, import-from-excel

I am using third party software to import Data from Excel, which only support Integration using ODBC, I am using following connection string

```
Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=C:\a.xlsx
```

Some times it gives error, which is because of mixed data types in their columns

I have searched for the solution, but it is through oledb and not using ODBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a lot of time searching for a solution and didn't find any workaround using ODBC and the `Microsoft Excel Driver`. Either make sure your excel files do not have any mixed-typed-columns (what is basically impossible to achieve, especially if you receive data from third party sources) or do not use ODBC to read the data, but stick to OleDb (which supports `IMEX=1`) or an other approach, like `libxl`, `libxls`, etc.